Deploy Power Pages in a new production enviroment fails on dependancies
Trying to deploy a new Power Pages site to a production environment.  The developer created the site in a development environment, so it cannot be promoted to production. I was following the sparse documentation and it told me to use a Solution.
I used the "Add Existing" to move the site into a Solution in the Development environment.  Then, I exported the solution and imported it into the new production environment per the instructions.  There is an option to create a pipeline, which I tried, as well as the Export to a file.  Both fail due to dependencies.
The documentation says to view the dependencies with the view dependency button.  If you click the button, there's nothing there, its empty.  And looking at the error details its all views and forms created for the website.  So why are these not being deployed?  There doesn't seem to be any facility to export these objects that could import them into the other solution.  Not sure what the next step would be.  Is it something to do with Dataverse?

Unzip the exported solution file. You will see a solution.xml
open and find tag
<MissingDependencies>...</MissingDependencies>
remove everything from between these tags so that it is empty. Then zip the folder again and import it to production.
P.S. Make sure that solution.xml and other files are on the root folder of zipped file. it shouldnt be nested in a sub directory.
